# C# - How to capitalize first letter 'only' on a paragraph? (Combined with regex)

Tags: c#, regex

So I had an assignment where when I input "a a.a. a", it should had output of "A a.A. A", but my output produce "Aa a.A. A" instead

This the code that handle the logic

```
private void mnuSentenize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ActiveMdiChild != null)
        {
            frmNotepad SNTZ = (frmNotepad)ActiveMdiChild;
            string Input = ((frmNotepad)ActiveMdiChild).FileContent.ToString();
            var Result = (char.ToUpper(Input[0]) + (Regex.Replace(Input, @"([.]\b[a-z]|[.] \b[a-z]|[?]\b[a-z]|[?] \b[a-z]|[!]\b[a-z]|[!] \b[a-z])", X => X.Value.ToUpper())));
            SNTZ.FileContent = Result.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I use regex to handle the replacement, but so far failed to find a way to capitalize the first char without making extra char pop out from nowhere

Comment: BUt the last letter in a word is capitalized in your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a regex to find the first lowercase character in each sentence:

```
(?<=(?:^|\.)\s*)\p{Ll}
```

`\p{Ll}` will match any lowercase letter, and the lookbehind will make sure it's the first letter of the string, or the first letter after a period, ignoring whitespace.

Here's how to use it:

```
var str = "a a.a. a";
var result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=(?:^|\.)\s*)\p{Ll}", m => m.Value.ToUpper());
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/1X4qCh)

---

As for your original code, your error is that you concatenate the first letter uppercased with the regex replacement result of the *whole string*. Try `Regex.Replace(Input.Substring(1), ...` instead. You should also check the string is at least one character long.

Comment: Alternatively, without look-behind (which is usually costly), `((?:^|\.)\s*)(\p{Ll})`. The replacement code must be changed a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, it worked

Fixed code:

```
private void mnuSentenize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ActiveMdiChild != null)
        {
            frmNotepad SNTZ = (frmNotepad)ActiveMdiChild;
            string Input = ((frmNotepad)ActiveMdiChild).FileContent.ToString();
            var Result = Regex.Replace(Input, @"((?<=(?:^|\.)\s*)\p{Ll}|[.]\b[a-z]|[.] \b[a-z]|[?]\b[a-z]|[?] \b[a-z]|[!]\b[a-z]|[!] \b[a-z])", X => X.Value.ToUpper());
            SNTZ.FileContent = Result.ToString();
        }
    }
```